# can't resolve method super when using custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to use ListView with custom ArrayAdapter, however when I try to call ***super*** in the constructor, it gives me this error :

> cannot resolve method'(android.content.Context, int, java.lang.String)

Here's my piece of code

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String values;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String values) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_second,values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}
```

what did I miss? thanks in return!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You constructor should pass a String array or String Arraylist in super.

The error says that you don't have a super constructor with just a string as a parameter